# FibonacciHeap increase_key implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, fibonacci-heap

.

Hi guys,

I'm using Erel Segal's C++ STL FibonacciHeap http://ideone.com/9jYnv and I think it's lacking of a increase_key() method.

```
/**
  * template Fibonacci Heap 
  *
  * @ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap
  * @ref http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~aaw/Jason/FibonacciHeapAlgorithm.html
  * @author Erel Segal http://tora.us.fm/rentabrain
  * @date 2010-11-11
  */
```

I'm about to implement it myself, but I've not found many references to theoretical implementation of that.

Can you give me some tips on how increase_key operation should be done?

Answer (score 1):

## [Boost.Heap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/heap.html)

Just use [`boost::heap::fibonacci_heap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html) - it has both [`increase`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html#idp18368448-bb) and [`decrease`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html#idp38883264-bb). It is reliable and [tested on different platforms](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/trunk/developer/heap.html).

It is header-only library, which means that you don't need to compile it and link against it.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny for your answer but unfortunately I can't use Boost libraries for my task.
I'm looking for some pseudo-code interpretation for increase_key() procedure so that I can write my own versino of that. By the way I will surely read Boost implementation as well.